# Login with Facebook account not working if the facebook account registered with phone number

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I have integrated "Login with Facebook" account in my website build with PHP. I used PHP SDK of Facebook. Everything worked fine until I tried to login via facebook account which was registered using mobile number. This facebook account does not have an email address added. It throws an error in facebook website & it is not redirecting to my website.

I am trying to get 'email' & 'public_profile' permissions. And I just need id & name. I am using v2.5 as default_graph_version.

I have not pasted the code here as I am very much using the SDK provided by Facebook without any changes. Please let me know if I need to paste my code here.

Here is screenshot of the error that I got.
[image]

Your help is very much appreciated.

**Update**: This is the code that i am using,

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'APP-ID-HERE',
    'app_secret' => 'APP-SECRET-HERE',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile']; 
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://my-test-domain.com/', $permissions);

echo '<a class="fb-login" href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with FB</a>';  `
```

**Update 2:** Here is App Restrictions settings in My App,
[image: FB - App Restrictions settings]

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with access restrictions configured in the app settings.

Comment: I did an detailed search on the web to find if there are any access restrictions configured in the app settings. But I did not find any useful information yet. FYI, my site was related to deals for wine products

Comment: App access restrictions are configured under Settings -> Advanced.

Comment: @CBore, Sorry I dont seem to find the Advanced Settings. I see it Under Settings > Security and login but not useful

Comment: You go into your app dashboard, you click Settings, that opens a submenu, and there you click Advanced ...

Comment: ah ok ok. you are referring the FB developer account. But it was set to 13+ in my App that is for everyone. The account I am testing has an age of 23.

Comment: And no restriction based on alcohol-related content or country either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For alcohol content related websites, there is an age limit which varies based on where you live. The user who is connecting via FB to a website which contains alcohol content need to be 25 years or older to use Facebook and Alchohol related apps for India & Sweden.

here the reference links,

http://help.untappd.com/discussions/social-account-issues/1466-facebook-error

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, SO suggests me to avoid extended discussions in comments. I hope this answer gives me a solution. Thanks Suriyasuresh. I have been spending long hours for this. I will let my customer know about this solution.